# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno -2] Name does not resolve)

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to connect mysql with docker using python. but this error is occurring. I am using python3. I am new in docker so I am unable to find any solution.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
MAINTAINER Fahim Ahmed Irfan

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache jpeg-dev
RUN apk --update add --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
      gcc build-base libffi-dev freetype-dev libpng-dev openblas-dev linux-headers mysql-dev zlib zlib-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR ./app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
User user
EXPOSE 8000
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python check_db.py --service-name mysql --ip db --port 3306 &&
             python manage.py makemigrations &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=localhost
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=app
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword

    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

check_db.py:

```
import socket
import time
import argparse
""" Check if port is open, avoid docker-compose race condition """

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check if port is open, avoid\
                                 docker-compose race condition')
parser.add_argument('--service-name', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--ip', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--port', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

# Get arguments
service_name = str(args.service_name)
port = int(args.port)
ip = str(args.ip)

# Infinite loop
while True:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result = sock.connect_ex((ip, port))
    if result == 0:
        print("{0} port is open! Bye!".format(service_name))
        break
    else:
        print("{0} port is not open! I'll check it soon!".format(service_name))
        time.sleep(3)
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
```

requirements.txt:

```
Django==2.1.3,<2.2.0
djangorestframework==3.9.0,<3.10.0
pymysql
```

The error is: **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno -2] Name does not resolve)")**

Dont know how to solve this. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got this working, I have made a few important changes that are required for your code.

```
WORKDIR app
```

`WORKDIR` does the creation of the directory `app` and also moving into the directory `app` so you can remove the statement `RUN mkdir /app`
As you also move to that directory so change the `COPY` statement to

```
COPY . .
```

first `.` is the place where the dockerfile exists and the second `.` is the app folder in the container. So it is always good to have dockerfile in the app folder.

```
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

the above code from the docker-compose is not required as you are copying the contents directly so mounting again is of no use.

```
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
```

Also, add the above environment variable to the db service in the docker-compose

```
- MYSQL_HOST=localhost
```

Please remove this environment variable as it is not required here.

```
image: mysql:5.7
```

I would recommend using version 5.7 as it is one of the stable ones I extensively use without many issues from the database server.

Comment: not working. Now this error is showing: **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")**

Comment: The problem is solved. I had to uninstall MySql from my laptop. But I dont know why this was conflicting with my docker.

Comment: Awesome, it should be because of the conflict on port 3306. 
Your local MySQL server has already taken the port 3306 making a conflict with the MySQL in the container.

Comment: You can send me an edit on my answer if you wish to.

Comment: Actually I have edited just as you suggested. But I need to add:  'volumes:
      - ./app:/app' these lines to docker-compose file otherwise python could not find manage.py file.

Comment: Can you tell me what port number should I use when 3306 is taken by another MySQL server??? or how can I get port numbers???

Comment: You can use the immediate next port `3307` but be careful that you have this port configured at the client-side too.